# Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index

Tags: excel, vba

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtpPd.png)i created an Excel userform. In the listbox when i try to delete a row it's giving me an error Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index.

> Delete Command

```
Private Sub CmdDelete_Click()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
If Cells(i, 1) = Listbox1.List(Listbox1.ListIndex) Then
Rows(i).Select
Selection.Delete
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the contents of the listbox and several rows of the spreadsheet? It's possible that every selection.delete is changing the value for End(xlUp).Row. It could also be ListIndex. I forget if it starts at 0 or 1, but you might be pointing at the wrong one?

Comment: I have 12 columns in the list box apparently the rows will increase day to day by user info

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you've got a selection made in the ListBox otherwise the value of the Listindex = -1

When deleting rows work from bottom to top

Do not use .select

Do you want to update the ListBox after Clicking?

Slightly adjusted code (not fully qualified ranges/cells):

```
Private Sub CmdDelete_Click()
Dim i As Long
    If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
        For i = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            If Cells(i, 1) = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 0) Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I selected one row in listbox but it's deleting multiple rows at a time

Comment: If Cells(i, 1) = Listbox1.List(Listbox1.ListIndex) Then....................should be here somewhere the error

Comment: Every row gets deleted when the cell in range A.. matches the  first column in the selected row in the ListBox. Wasn’t this the purpose?

Comment: if i select a row in the listbox the selected item must get deleted. but it's deleting multiple rows